# Possible to map public action parameters to different fields in MVC 4 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

So say I have a action that looks like:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string ovar_token1, string ovar_token2, string some_other)
{
    // Do some stuff here
}
```

What I would like to do is have the parameters called something else that is more agreeable to our naming conventions while still permitting the modelbinding to bind to them.

So probably decorating with some custom annotation like:

```
[Params("ovar_token1", token)]
[Params("ovar_token2", token2)]
[Params("some_other", data)]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string token1, string token2, string data)
{
    // Do some stuff here
}
```

Anyone ever tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `BindAttribute`:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(
    [Bind(Prefix="ovar_token1")]string token1,
    [Bind(Prefix="ovar_token2")]string token2,
    [Bind(Prefix="some_other")]string data)
```

Comment: I like it...simple and easy to implement.  I thought the Prefix was used for more of a pattern match but it seems to work so I will take it.

Comment: @ewahner, as a matter of fact you are still matching a pattern, right?